# how to create a duplicate table with the same constraints as the original in Oracle

Tags: database-design, oracle-12c, table

I usually create a duplicate table like this:

`CREATE TABLE TEST_NEW AS SELECT * FROM TEST;`

This does create a replica of the original table, however, the constraints aren't replicated.

is there a way to replicate the constraints as well?

I have also tried this:

`CREATE TABLE TEST_NEW AS SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE 2=1`

This also replicates the structure and only creates the `Check` constraint.

Comment: generally speaking, constraints must be recreated separately.